# Make proxy container for running docker MySQL container

Tags: mysql, proxy, docker

I have running docker MySQL container on production server.
I need to connect to MySQL database from another server.
Container just have EXPOSE 3306, but no binded ports.

So, i understand that binding port to a running container is not possible.

I  thinking about creating new "proxy" container, bind ports to listen outside and link it to existing MySQL container.

Will this work?

Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

Just run your container with `-P` option or with `-p <host_machine_port>:<container_port>`

For MySQL it can be done with `docker run -p 3306:3306 mysql`

And you can connect to MySQL through `yourmysqldomain.com:3306`